# c memory suballocator, having troubles with structs, linked-list and pointer casting

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, casting, struct

i'm trying to make a memory suballocator and initialise it, i think im handling the pointers wrongly. This suballocator mallocs a block of memory and then divides it up with 32byte "header" placed in the front bytes to indicate its size.

The header is supposed to be a circular double link-list. Therefore at first initialisation, the next and prev values in the struct are pointed at itself.

Been trying to work at this for hours am tired and am pretty frustrated at the pointers now..

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
static byte *memory = NULL;

struct header;

typedef struct _header {
    int size;
    struct header * next;
    struct header * prev;
}header;

static header* free_list_ptr;


void allocator_init(u_int32_t size){

    memory = (byte*) malloc(size);

    //initialize free_list_ptr;
    free_list_ptr = (header*) memory;

    free_list_ptr->size = size;
    free_list_ptr->prev = free_list_ptr; //error: assignment from incompatible pointer type
    free_list_ptr->next = free_list_ptr; //error: assignment from incompatible pointer type
}
```

Comment: You now seem to have edited the initial code in the question which makes all answers redundant

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to change the question without indicating your changes.  It will make the answers harder to follow, or even nonsensical.  Your original declaration of a static `free_list_ptr` was valid, you just needed to use the address-of operator (`&`) to assign the address of that structure to the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration for `free_list_ptr` is not a pointer. It has type `header`. I think you want

```
static header *free_list_ptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the address of `free_list_ptr` using the address-of operator (`&`):

```
free_list_ptr.prev = &free_list_ptr;
```

[Edited to correct member reference syntax.]

Comment: You probably mean `free_list_ptr.prev = &free_list_ptr;`, but this won't accomplish what the OP is trying to do.